# Como transformar um string em HTML C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, string, conversão

Estou usando um componente e preciso carregar ele com trecho HTML que vem em uma variável. Pra isso criei esse JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mentions-kinder').html('@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.FormulaRecover)');
});
```

Mas mesmo assim quando rodo, ele não carrega o código, e fica assim:

> [image: Foto 1]

Se o JQuery lesse o código igual o print acima dava certo, mas o código quando inspeciono a página fica assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mentions-kinder').html('&lt;span class=&quot;mention badge badge-warning&quot; contenteditable=&quot;false&quot; serialized-mention=&quot;[#Quantidade de Visitas](tag:12)&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;tag-trigger&quot;&gt;Parametro: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;tag-value&quot;&gt;Quantidade de Visitas&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;delete-mention tag-delete&quot;&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;icon-remove&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&#160;&lt;span class=&quot;mention badge badge-primary&quot; contenteditable=&quot;false&quot; serialized-mention=&quot;(area:104)&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;area-trigger&quot;&gt;Area: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;area-value&quot;&gt;Alessandro Spricigo&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;delete-mention area-delete&quot;&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;icon-remove&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&#160;*');
});
```

E fica tudo errado. Alguma ideia pra isso ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você tem uma `string` de `html` ela não é renderizada no `DOM`, para que esta `string` possa ser renderiza é necessário chamar o método `Html.Raw()` passando a `string html`. O método `Html.Raw()` Transforma a `string` em uma marcação `html`.

**Solução**

No seu caso você deve utilizar como abaixo:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.FormulaRecover))
```